# Python3 : How to Use enumerate() to Print total items in a list?

Tags: python-3.7, enumerate

Instead of using `len`, i am using `enumerate` function. In it, how can i get total number of items?

**Sample code:-**

```
data = ['bat','cat','eat','fat','தொப்பி','எலி']
for itemNum, item in enumerate(data):
    print(itemNum+1, end='')
```

result: **123456**

expected result: **6**

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by following piece of code

```
data = ['bat','cat','eat','fat','தொப்பி','எலி']
count = 0
for itemNum, item in enumerate(data):
    count = count + 1
    
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
for itemNum, item in enumerate(data):
    i=i+1

print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `enumerate` is to avoid the above said, *count method*. When compare, i think, enumerate function is advanced one. hope that i am correct in this issue.

```
data = ['bat','cat','eat','fat','தொப்பி','எலி']
py_no= [  0,    1,    2,    3,    4,   5 ]
human= [  1,    2,    3,    4,    5,   6 ]

for itemNum, item in enumerate(data):
    itemNum2tuple = tuple(str(itemNum+1)) # immutable; for human number adding +1
    itemNum2tuple_string = itemNum2tuple[0] # to avoid brackets, ...
print(itemNum2tuple_string) # indentation for the loop end.
print(int(itemNum2tuple_string)) # to further need, changing as integer
```

**Expected output:** 6